# Can a habitable world function like a Tesla Coil?

Tags: science-based, geology, electricity, electromagnetism, power-sources

I am trying to come up with a fun planet with "advanced" but primitive tech. We all know Tesla missed some critical physics when envisioning his global transmission network for power. But what if things were different?

**What conditions could exist on a habitable planet that would allow the planet to function as a giant Tesla coil, powering wireless devices, OR allow the people on the planet to charge the planet in a way similar to what Tesla was envisioning?** Could a planet, for example, have a rapidly spinning nuclear-powered natural core and appropriate metals to simulate the needs of such a device? A moon orbiting or spinning rapidly inside the magnetic field of another planet? A metallic world like in [A Boy and his Tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Frankowski)? It can be a weird and unlikely anomaly, but naturally possible. It can be a world that was at some point terraformed, but capable of supporting a civilization with tech advancing through the 19th and 20th centuries. If short-lived, the effect should last long enough for a civilization to work it's way through an advancing civilization (say, 10,000 years). The less people need to do to make this work, the better. People will be basically human, but if slight alterations are needed (increased radiation resistance within reasonable limits, for example) that is acceptable. Bonus points if the planet itself generates the power used naturally.

"That won't work," is acceptable with appropriate details.

Comment: A [Tesla coil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_coil) is a passive device. It is basically a transformer with embellishments. I have no idea what you mean by having a planet functioning like a transformer. (And I don't see how a high-voltage high-frequency electric field, which is what a Tesla coil produces, could be used to charge anything. The main use of Tesla coils is to generate pretty sparks in order to separate punters from their money.)

Comment: @AlexP I mean the planet somehow generates a field around itself that devices can tap into the power from, OR that the locals can pump power into in a similar way that Nicolai Tesla once imagined he could to make a global wireless power network. I figured there would need to be power input from something.

Comment: Oh, and what is the relationship with a Tesla coil? The question explicitly asks how to make a planet functioned like a doubly-tuned electric transformer.

Comment: @AlexP It's Tesla's vision, that he hoped to execute with Tesla coil-like devices, that I want to know if it can be achieved. My understanding was the Earth and atmosphere wasn't conductive enough, and the system not efficient enough, to make the idea work. But what could? It would make for a fun civilization to play with.

Comment: (1) Tesla's vision was of *transmitting* power wirelessly over large distances. He had no particularly visionary vision about how to generate that power. (2) Telsa's ideas of long-distance wireless power transmission don't work for obvious reasons. Or rather, they sort-of work and have real-life applications, but the power losses are horrendous, so that coupled-tuned-circuits wireless power transmission is used only when really really useful. For example, a wireless phone charger, which transmits power over a whopping long distance of a few millimeters, wastes about 30% of the power *at best*.

Comment: @AlexP EXACTLY! So is there any possible way to make that work on a planetary level? Leo Frankowski's planet had a layer of solid gold. Who knows? a freak of planetary formation? It can be pretty outrageous, but just be something that COULD happen in perfect conditions. It sounds like you have the core of a frame challenge answer, and that is acceptable as well.

Comment: I think your estimated minimum timeline for developing an advanced civilization is far too short. Anatomically modern humans have been around ~250K years, but it wasn't until ~30KYA that we domesticated wolves, and ~12KYA until we first started planting seeds for food. That leaves >220K years of people like us with what we'd probably consider zero advanced technology. Humans didn't even have _bricks_ until ~7KYA. Against that scale, a 10KY phenomenon that coincides with the latest ~500 years of tech is practically surgical precision. I'd skew towards a geological timescale.

Comment: @Tom I only really care about the period around and after the development of electricity.  I didn't want to exclude anything that would be a potentially short-term effect. What happens before is less relevant, and once an advanced space-faring society develops, tech is pretty high. So think 1800 to the year 11800, and that gives plenty of time. It also leaves the window open to a culture re-inventing technology (the terraforming option).

Answer (score 2):

### No

You'll have to come from far, I'm afraid.. the total energy of [Earth's magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field) is surprisingly low, that is about [950 KW](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40948-015-0006-y), which can put a 30 x 10e-3 Tesla magnetic field strength to move our compass needles.

**Provide all power for the planet**

Currently, the world's population consumes [15 terawatts of power](https://www.theworldcounts.com/stories/current_world_energy_consumption). Say you'd like to distribute world's energy consumption, assuming field strength is proportional to  energy, the magnetic field strength needed for distribution would become (15x10e12/950000)*30x10e-3 is

**4.73 x 10e5 Tesla.**

This is a huge field. Animals would probably get cooked in milliseconds. A [neutron star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(magnetic_field)) might invoke it, not a planet.

**Mobile phones only**

The above outcome would provide 1850W per inhabitant. Say you'd need only 18.5W for mobile phones, you still get

**4730 Tesla.**

To compare, an amount of only 16 Tesla will levitate a frog,

[image]

.. is that dangerous ? yes,

*The human body starts to suffer from current induction when the exterior magnetic field reaches around 7 to 8 Tesla. Symptoms include increase in body temperature, diminishing brain functions and even hallucinations*

ref: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119999/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-human-with-a-powerful-magnet